# Fullscreen element with `requestFullscreen()` doesn't work on chrome on ipad (iPad OS 13.6)

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, fullscreen, ipados, webkitrequestfullscreen

I'm trying to make an element enter "full screen" mode with `requestFullscreen()` API, and it works great in all browsers except for Chrome on iPad.

I tried this package and it also works great in all browsers, including Safari on iPad, but not Chrome on iPad.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull

There's even a ticket on that package from people complaining about the same issue, but with no solution.

I tried to search for this with no luck.

I wonder how Youtube does it on Chrome on iPad?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue with one of my react components (using fscreen underlying) From what I have read so far ìOS chrome does not support document.fullscreenEnabled (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenEnabled)